# Microsoft Exchange, Outlook, and Domains

Tags: email, address-book, exchange-2013

I have a domain set up which is corp.domainname.com

When setting up email addresses it only allows user@corp.domainname.com. How do I make exchange use user@domainname.com instead of @corp.domainname.com? I still want the user to be able to log in the corp domain on their computer and use outlook with exchange.

Comment: You can't.  That isn't how domains work.

Answer (score 0):

If your login/AD domain is "corp.domainname.com" then that's the domain that users need to specify when logging in, since it's where the credentials are stored.

It will also be the domain Exchange sets itself up to work with by default, unless you specify otherwise during initial setup.

If you want to also use just "domainname.com" for email addresses, then you'll need to put in an additional MX record into your public DNS for that domain, and setup Exchange to (also) work with that domain.

Check out this MS TechNet section to get started: [Accepted Domains](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124423(v=exchg.150).aspx)